# How can I type a single backslash in my code in python?

Tags: python

```
def format_changer_m():
    date=input('Enter date in DD/MM/YYYY: ') 
    x=date.split('/')
    return (x[1]+"\\"+x[0]+'/'+x[2])
```

this code returns with two backslashes  MM\DD/YYYY

```
def format_changer_m():
    date=input('Enter date in DD/MM/YYYY: ') 
    x=date.split('/')
    print(x[1]+"\\"+x[0]+'/'+x[2])
```

but this code returns only one backslash MM\DD/YYYY

I am using Jupiter Notebook.

Comment: Type "backslash python" in Google and you'll get the answer.

Comment: What do you want to achive ? Try: `print(x[1]+"\\"+x[0]+'/'+x[2])`

Comment: I did there were multiple solutions like using "\\" and r"\"" but they both print two backslashes instead of one, and i want to print a single slash only.

Answer (score 1):

> I did there were multiple solutions like using "\" and r"\"" but they both print two backslashes instead of one, and i want to print a single slash only.

There is *only one* backslash,these options are right, the reason why you see two is because you used it in the shell.

If you used `print(xxx)` , you will see it renders correctly.

For exsample:

```
def format_changer_m():
    date=input('Enter date in DD/MM/YYYY: ') 
    x=date.split('/')
    return x[1]+"\\"+x[0]+'\\'+x[2]
print(format_changer_m())
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes in strings are used as an escape character. You will need to use `"\\"` to output a single `\` this code will not run be cause you are instead escaping the `"` so that it is treated as a character within the string. google: escape characters python.

sidenote: you don't need brackets for a return function